# Sorting and filtering data based on join date

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this

```
Name | Join date
AAAA | Jun 1, 2010
```

What I want to do is to use that data to add columns to the right which have the next 18 months like this:

```
Jan 2015 | Feb 2015 | Mar 2015 | etc
```

And for the names to only appear if they have a milestone (10, 20 , 30) within the next 18 months period.

Is there anyway for me to do this? Would I need to write a macro of some kind for it? Or is a set of formulas enough for this? I would like it to pull data from a list in sheet 1, and output that into sheet 2.

I've added an example screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHeDg.png

The different colors are for what kind of milestone they are (10, 20, 30) years

Comment: I've just added an example of what the final one should look like (Those are the ones I've done manually by hand)

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what you mean by you can't tell?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what is going to need to happen in order to write anything, but I can provide you with some ideas to get you through.  You will have to connect the dots, so to speak.

```
Sub LoopFormatting()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheet As String
Dim joinDate As Date
Dim gap As Long

sheet = "Sheet1"
lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 

'Loop through Sheet1. 
For lRow = 2 To lastRow

    'get the join date and name it as a variable
    joinDate = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, "B")  ' Where is the joinDate

    'Loop through columns from n To n + 18
    For lCol = n to n +18   'set n as the column number that your months start

        'set gap variable here based on month(JoinDate) and month(column Month Date)
        gap = Month(joinDate) - Month(columnDate)   'You will know these variable names

        'Evaluate with Select Case gap and Set the Value for the cell with the .interior.colorindex property
        Select Case gap
            Case Is = 120
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, lCol) = dateValue 'The date you are entering in the column
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, lCol).Interior.colorindex = 3 'Set whatever you want here. 
            Case Is = 240
               'insert your choices for formatting and values to be set
            Case Is = 360
               'insert your choices for formatting and values to be set
        End Select
    Next lCol
Next lRow
End Sub
```

**LINKS:** 
[Color Palette](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)